# How to match the number with leading zero by excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am storing 11 digit mobile numbers with leading zero in an excel worksheet column as "CUSTOM (00000000000)" formatted column. Now I have created a user form to get any mobile number as user input (from I12 cell also as CUSTOM 00000000000 formatted column). The mobile numbers are stored in the "Database" worksheet and the form is in "Form" worksheet. So I am trying to perform by the following VBA code in excel:

```
Sub mobSearch()
    Dim mobNum As Long
    Dim mobLoc As Long
    Dim rowSerial As Long

    mobNum = Format(Sheets("Form").Range("I12").Value,"00000000000")
    mobLoc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(mobNum, Sheets("Database").Range("H:H"), 0)
    rowSerial = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError _
    (Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Database").Range("A:A"), mobLoc), 0) + 1
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rowSerial = 0 Then
    
        MsgBox "No record found.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No Record"
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
End Sub
```

and unfortunately, it is showing "No Record" although I can see the mobile number is stored in the Database Worksheet in H column with leading zero.

How to resolve this?

Comment: The format of a cell does not make that cell equal to what is shown.  If you are using a custom format on the cells the value is the number without the leading `0`s.  You will want to search with the same thing, no leading `0`s

Comment: Also make sure since the values in H are numbers that you are using a number on the search.  `Format()` changes the number to text and to vlookup `"1"<>1`

Comment: Instead of matching a string `mobNum` match `CDec(Sheets("Form").Range("I12").Value)` Note that a `Long` cannot take a 11 digit number if it starts with a high number. To be save convert the value into a decimal instead of a long or use the value directly without `CDec`.

Comment: Assuming that you're not doing any math on the phone numbers, consider storing them as strings instead of numbers. Then `MATCH` will work as expected.